# How can I show a saved value that has just been updated in a jqGrid without reloading the entire grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have my jqgrid working fine with the grid reloading fully every time, however I would like to not fully reload the grid until the page is refreshed. The reason is that the user may be on page 5 of 10, and when the grid reloads it resets it back to the beginning - I want the user to stay on the same page with the updated data.

Another approach I am looking into is saving the grid state somehow, the page it's on, etc and navigate back to that after reload. I tried this using this code

```
$('#grid').jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }])
```

but it does not show the updated data. What am I missing?

**Here is my full jqGrid code:**

```
            $('#grid').jqGrid({
            url: 'GetLocations',
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Address Line 1', 'Address Line 2', 'City', 'StateId', 'State', 'RegionId', 'Region', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Fax'],
               colModel: [
                { name: 'LocationId', jsonmap: 'LocationId', index: 'LocationId', width: 40, key: true },
                {
                    name: 'LocationName', jsonmap: 'LocationName', index: 'LocationName', sortable: true, width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 64, maxlength: 64 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'AddressLine1', jsonmap: 'AddressLine1', index: 'AddressLine1', sortable: false, width: 150,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 64, maxlength: 64 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'AddressLine2', jsonmap: 'AddressLine2', index: 'AddressLine2', sortable: false, width: 50,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: false },
                    editoptions: { size: 64, maxlength: 64 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'City', jsonmap: 'City', index: 'City', width: 100,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 64, maxlength: 64 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'State_Id', jsonmap: 'State.Id', index: 'State_Id', editable: false, hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'State', jsonmap: 'State.Name', index: 'State', width: 50, sortable: true, editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: 'GetLookupItems?lookupType=states',
                        buildSelect: createSelectList
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Region_Id', jsonmap: 'Region.Id', index: 'Region_Id', editable: false, hidden: true
                },
                {
                    name: 'Region', jsonmap: 'Region.Name', index: 'Region', width: 80, sortable: true, editable: true,
                    edittype: 'select',
                    editoptions: {
                        dataUrl: 'GetLookupItems?lookupType=regions',
                        buildSelect: createSelectList
                    }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Zip', jsonmap: 'Zip', index: 'Zip', width: 40, sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: true },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 16, maxlength: 16 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Phone', jsonmap: 'Phone', index: 'Phone', width: 80, sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: false },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 16, maxlength: 16 }
                },
                {
                    name: 'Fax', jsonmap: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', width: 80, sortable: false,
                    editable: true,
                    editrules: { required: false },
                    formoptions: { elmsuffix: ' *' },
                    editoptions: { size: 16, maxlength: 16 }
                }],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 25,
            rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            sortable: true,
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'Name',
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'Class Locations',
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            loadonce: true, /* needs to be true for client side paging to work */
            loadtext: 'Loading...'

        });
        $('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false },

            { /* edit options */
                url: 'UpdateLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                //afterSubmit: ReloadGrid,
                width: 500,
                bottominfo: '* required fields',
                bSubmit: 'Save',
                recreateForm: true
            },
            { /* add options */
                url: 'InsertLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                //afterSubmit: ReloadGrid,
                width: 500,
                bottominfo: '* required fields',
                bSubmit: 'Save',
                recreateForm: true
            },
            { /* delete options */
                url: 'DeleteLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                //afterSubmit: ReloadGrid
            }
        );
        $('#grid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
    });

    function ReloadGrid() {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
        //$('#grid').jqGrid().trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);
        return [true, '']; /* no error */
    }
```

**Updated code with partial solution (removed colModel for succinctness):**

```
 $('#grid').jqGrid({
            url: 'GetLocations',
            datatype: 'json',
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Address Line 1', 'Address Line 2', 'City', 'StateId', 'State', 'RegionId', 'Region', 'Zip', 'Phone', 'Fax'],
            colModel: [

         ...

            ],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 25,
            rowList: [10, 25, 50, 100],
            sortable: true,
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'Name',
            ignoreCase: true,
            caption: 'Class Locations',
            height: '100%',
            autowidth: true,
            loadonce: true, /* needs to be true for client side paging to work */
            loadtext: 'Loading...'
        });
        $('#grid').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: false },

            { /* edit options */
                url: 'UpdateLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true,
                //afterSubmit: ReloadGrid,
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    var $self = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $self.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);
                    }, 50);
                    return [true, ''];
                },
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                width: 500,
                bottominfo: '* required fields',
                bSubmit: 'Save',
                recreateForm: true
            },
            { /* add options */
                url: 'InsertLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true,
                afterSubmit: function () {
                    var $self = $(this);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $self.jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);
                    }, 50);
                    return [true, ''];
                },
                reloadAfterSubmit: false,
                width: 500,
                bottominfo: '* required fields',
                bSubmit: 'Save',
                recreateForm: true
            },
            { /* delete options */
                url: 'DeleteLocation',
                closeOnEscape: true,
                reloadAfterSubmit: false
            }
        );
        $('#grid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn' });
    });

    // not used...
    function ReloadGrid() {
        $('#grid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true, page: 2}]);
        return [true, '']; /* no error */
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement your requirement you have to set `reloadAfterSubmit` [option of form editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#properties) to false. The default value of `reloadAfterSubmit` is true, so jqGrid reloads the grid at the end of form editing (see [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L790)). Triggering of `reloadGrid` with some parameters can't solve the problem because jqGrid will reload the grid **one more time** in case of default `reloadAfterSubmit: true` value.

So you have to use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` first of all. Then you can either use

```js
afterSubmit: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $self.jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" })
            .trigger("reloadGrid", [{ current: true }]);
    }, 50);
}
```

or just do nothing in case of Delete and Edit operation and change the response of server (from `url: 'InsertLocation'`) so that it returns the `id` of new added row and modify the id of added row to the value inside of `afterSubmit` callback. In the last case `afterSubmit` callback should return the id of new row as the third element of returned array (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.formedit.js#L768-L769) of jqGrid code).

Comment: Thanks Oleg! This has gotten me partially there..  I now have add and delete working as needed after setting reloadAfterSubmit:false and adding the afterSubmit function code you provided. However my edit still seems to refresh the entire grid. I will update my original post with these changes. I am not sure I understand your suggestion to return the id for the Edit (and delete) operation? I already have the id locally, so why would I need it again? And it seems that if resetting datatype:json for add worked then it would also work for edit operation? Any additional ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @Tone: To simplify my suggestion let us you just use `reloadAfterSubmit: false` **without** any `afterSubmit`. jqGrid will add new row base of `addedrow` parameter (default is "first"). So the row will be added as the first row wnd you can have more as 25 rows (`rowNum`) in the grid. Delete operation will remove the row and selection. You can have less rows as 25 (`rowNum`). The main problem with Add operation: jqGrid don't know rowid of new row. If you load the data from database and the id will be generated automatically then the server have to return the id of new added row back to jqGrid.

Comment: @Tone: Edit with `reloadAfterSubmit: false` and **without** `afterSubmit` should work almost correct. The only problem is that the edited row will stay on the same place and reloading of the grid could help to place row position corresponds to `sortname` (`Name` in your case). If the order is not so important for you then you should just remove `afterSubmit` for edit operation.

Comment: Perfect! Thought I had tried that...guess not. I do not need the row to resort, in fact that would potentially confuse the user as it would disappear from the current page. Thanks for the help and explanation behind the solution.

Comment: @Tone: You are welcome! `afterSubmit` callback have `jqXHR` object (superset of `XMLHttpRequest`) as the first parameter. So the server could return id of new row (generated from database for example) in the response. In the case `jqXHR.responseText` will be the id and the code `afterSubmit: function (jqXHR) { return [true, "", jqXHR.responseText]; }` would forward server based id of new row to jqGrid. In the case the new row will be added to grid with the rowid. You can examine `id` attribute of the row by Developer Tools.